# I am trying to monitor Azure managed cassandra nodes using Promethous and Grafana

Tags: cassandra, monitoring

I have setup promethous and Grafana on Azure VM to monitor Azure managed cassandra using below document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-instance-apache-cassandra/visualize-prometheus-grafana

Cassandra cluster Nodes and Azure VM are in same Vnet.
Cassandra nodes are showing up in portal, I am able to telnet to these Nodes from azure VM where I configure Prometheus and Grafana.
But on Prometheus dashboard I am seeing node as down. Do you have any leads on this issue.
[image: Prometheus]

Comment: @YashwantPawarm I have simply switched to leveraging [DataStax Astra DB](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-astra) which has monitoring Health dashboard built right in [along with many other serverless DBaaS capabilities] and it is very convenient to operate in any cloud of my choice. Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a minimum of 3 (depending on the size of your cluster, you may have more) nodes showing under the mcac section. These should be the IP addresses of the nodes you see displayed in the Data Center pane in Azure Portal.

The fact that you only have 1 node showing suggests that you might have used the IP address of "PrometheusEndpoint" that displays in the Overview page in Azure portal (unfortunately that is a cosmetic bug - ignore that IP address).

Hope this helps!